ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to LSTM: {'batch_input_shape'} in Keras
I'm trying to build and train a stateful LSTM model using Keras in TensorFlow, but I keep encountering a ValueError when specifying the batch_input_shape parameter.
The error message:
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to LSTM: {'batch_input_shape': (1, 1, 14)}

Here's a simplified version of my code:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

# Load your data
file_path = 'path_to_your_file.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Create 'date' column with the first day of each month
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['tahun'].astype(str) + '-' + data['bulan'].astype(str) + '-01')
data['date'] = data['date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Group by 'date' and sum the 'amaun_rm' column
df_sales = data.groupby('date')['amaun_rm'].sum().reset_index()

# Create a new dataframe to model the difference
df_diff = df_sales.copy()
df_diff['prev_amaun_rm'] = df_diff['amaun_rm'].shift(1)
df_diff = df_diff.dropna()
df_diff['diff'] = df_diff['amaun_rm'] - df_diff['prev_amaun_rm']

# Create new dataframe from transformation from time series to supervised
df_supervised = df_diff.drop(['prev_amaun_rm'], axis=1)
for inc in range(1, 13):
    field_name = 'lag_' + str(inc)
    df_supervised[field_name] = df_supervised['diff'].shift(inc)

# Adding moving averages
df_supervised['ma_3'] = df_supervised['amaun_rm'].rolling(window=3).mean().shift(1)
df_supervised['ma_6'] = df_supervised['amaun_rm'].rolling(window=6).mean().shift(1)
df_supervised['ma_12'] = df_supervised['amaun_rm'].rolling(window=12).mean().shift(1)
df_supervised = df_supervised.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
df_supervised = df_supervised.fillna(df_supervised.mean())

# Split the data into train and test sets
train_set, test_set = df_supervised[0:-6].values, df_supervised[-6:].values
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(train_set)
train_set_scaled = scaler.transform(train_set)
test_set_scaled = scaler.transform(test_set)

# Split into input and output
X_train, y_train = train_set_scaled[:, 1:], train_set_scaled[:, 0]
X_test, y_test = test_set_scaled[:, 1:], test_set_scaled[:, 0]
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))

# Check the shape of X_train
print("X_train shape:", X_train.shape)  # Should output (44, 1, 14)

# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(1, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False)

# Summarize the model
model.summary()

What I have tried:

I verified the shape of X_train which is (44, 1, 14).
I attempted to use input_shape instead of batch_input_shape, which led to different errors.
I ensured that the versions of TensorFlow and Keras are compatible.

System Information:

Python version: 3.12

TensorFlow version: 2.17.0

Keras version: 3.4.1


Question:
How can I correctly specify the batch_input_shape for my stateful LSTM model in Keras to avoid this error? Are there any specific version requirements or additional configurations needed?

The error message says that batch_input_shape is not a valid keyword argument for LSTM().  Can you explain why you thought this was correct?

I referred to documentation and examples that used batch_input_shape for defining stateful LSTM models. Is it there might be a discrepancy with my TensorFlow/Keras version. Could you advise on the correct approach for my setup? or u have any other idea? @JohnGordon

Can you provide links to that documentation?

https://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/

How exactly did you determine the tensorflow/keras versions on your system?

print(tf.version)
print(keras.version)
im using this. any idea?

You said this was a simplified version of the code.  If you run this exact simplified code, do you get the same error?

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 4 dimension(s). this error. i dont understand i already use 3dims but still it detect 4dims. so i dont have any idea.

I'm confused -- where did this new ValueError come from?

okay sorry, same error.. batch_input_shape is not valid argument for LTSM? so how can revise that?

Could you share stack trace of the ValueError? batch_input_shape should be a valid argument for LTSM. You can confirm it by just running a sample snippet model = Sequential(); model.add(LSTM(10, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1), stateful=True)) The error likely come from somewhere else

You linked to unofficial documentation, the official documentation does not show the parameter you are asking about: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/

In oder to provide batch_input_shape, you need to have InputLayer as a first layer in your sequential model.
Below is the code with modifications.
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(1, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(4, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False)

# Summarize the model
model.summary()

